# How to setup the Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am very new to fabric.js. I have downloaded the fabric.js, but I don't know how to start it. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="450" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
        canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));

        canvas.selectionColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
        canvas.selectionBorderColor = 'red';
        canvas.selectionLineWidth = 5;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this script I supposed to see a circle. I followed this example: http://fabricjs.com/customization/

But why I couldn't see anything; what I am missing?

Comment: Sorry actually, I have edited the question.. I didn't completed the previous one..

Answer (score 16):

The parameter of `fabric.Canvas` should match the canvas `id` in HTML.

Change the line

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
```

to

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
```

This should work.