# How can I set up Fabric.js?

Tags: html, canvas, javascript, fabricjs

I just started looking into using fabric.js, and I'm finding very little resources on how to install it in my site. All I can find is a single [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695308/how-to-setup-the-fabric-js) that references the file "all.min.js", which upon a quick search of the unzipped file no longer exists.

I've scoured the internet for the past few hours, and it's looking like it is supposed to be common knowledge! I'm still stuck though.

**Which file should I link to in my HTML?**

Edit: Just to clarify, I downloaded a large ZIP file off fabric.js's github. I was confused as to which file I should link to to include the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fabric follows a pretty traditional distribution layout.

You want to use files from the `dist` directory. `fabric.js` for development work and `fabric.min.js` for the live site.

Answer (score 19):

## An even more modern fabric.js hello-world using *ES6 Modules* and vite (state of 2023)

Since I wrote the answer below, things have improved and it's become even *easier* using [ES6-Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and [vite](https://vitejs.dev/)

The ES6-Module change is trivial. Simply apply the following patch to `index.html`:

```
--- index.html.old      2023-07-19 20:06:57.824477914 +0200
+++ index.html  2023-07-19 19:56:13.651532983 +0200
@@ -11,7 +11,7 @@
     height="400"
     style="border:1px solid #000000;">
   </canvas>
-  <script src="main.js"></script>
+  <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

To use `vite`, install it instead of `webpack` using:

```
npm install --save-dev vite
```

Next you can run it as a dev-server by running:

```
./node_modules/.bin/vite serve
```

And build the resulting files using:

```
./node_module/.bin/vite build
```

As the commands are unwieldy they can be added to `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vite serve",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  ...
}
```

Then you can simply run `npm run build` or `npm run serve`

---

## A more modern fabric.js hello-world using *webpack*  (state of 2018)

### Advantages of this method

- `fabric.js` does not need to be committed to version control
- Given that all dependencies are in `package.json` only two commands are required to get up and running from scratch with your project: `git clone <url>` and `npm install`
- Updating to the latest fabric version is as easy as running `npm update`
- Not only the fabricjs code, but also your own code will be minified.
- and it gives you all other goodies provided by webpack

### Assumptions

This assumes...

- ... that you have the NPM `>= 5.2` (if I recall correctly, this is needed by webpack).
- ... that you have access to a CLI shell to run the `npm` and `webpack` commands.
- ... that the npm binaries are on your path. By default: `$HOME/.local/bin` on *nix systems

**NOTE**: You will *not* need superuser/root access to the system if you already have `npm` available.

### Preparations

First, initialise a new *npm* project:

```
mkdir my-fabric-project
cd my-fabric-project
npm init -y
```

Then install webpack into that folder (we will need this for later):

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```

Also, install `fabricjs` as this is our dependency for our project:

```
npm install --save fabric
```

The two `npm install` commands above will populate our `package.json` file containing production (fabricjs) and development (webpack & webpack-cli) dependencies.

**NOTE:** When installing webpack, I got errors regarding `cairo` at the time of this writing. But it seems they are harmless. `cairo` is a graphics library and I assume this is only needed if you want to run `fabricjs` in a `nodejs` process. Browsers are already capable of rendering graphics so when running `fabricjs` in client-side code this is a non-issue. Otherwise you may need to install required headers. I assume (not tested) that this error can be solved by installing the package `libcairo-dev` on debian-based systems.

### The Code

Now we have everything ready to get coding.

Create two folders `src` and `dist`, so our source tree becomes:

```
.
├── node_modules
|   ├...
|   └── ...
├── dist
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src

2 directories, 2 files
```

Create a HTML file `index.html` inside the `dist` folder with the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World FabricJS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas
    id="myCanvas"
    width="400"
    height="400"
    style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And also a javascript `index.js` in the `src` folder with the following contents:

```
import {fabric} from 'fabric';

function run() {
  let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
  let rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 20,
    height: 20
  });
  canvas.add(rect);
}

run();
```

This will give us the following directory structure:

```
.
├── node_modules
|   ├...
|   └── ...
├── dist
│   └── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    └── index.js

2 directories, 5 files
```

You may notice that `dist/index.html` references a file called `main.js` which does not exist. We need to run `webpack` to create it:

```
npx webpack
```

Your code should now work. Either open `dist/index.html` manually, or run a mini-web server from the console to test:

```
(cd dist && python3 -m http.server)
```

That's it!

This should get you started with your project and also allow you to leverage the power of webpack to easily split your code. Good luck & Have fun!

---

### Good To Know

- The filenames `dist/main.js` and `src/index.js` are the defaults when running `webpack` without a config
- `webpack` will create minified code in `dist/main.js` by default. This is because it runs in "production" mode by default. To change this, create a file named `webpack.config.js` with the following contents:

  ```
    module.exports = {
      mode: 'development'
    };
  ```

  You can use it running:

  ```
    npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
  ```

Comment: Excellent instructions. Coming from the future in Dec 2022 to confirm that this is the way to go if you want to start building FabricJS into your standard ES6 based build pipelines. And FabricJS is still the big kahuna amongst all the Canvas libraries and is a joy to work with.

Comment: @ultrasounder thanks for pinging this answer. It promped me to update it to an updated toolchain.

Answer (score 17):

All you need to do download the fabric.js from [**HERE**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js) and save it as js file named `fabric.js`, and create the html file suppose `index.html` with below content.

To run this example, these both `fabric.js` and `index.html` should be into one folder.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="fabric.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="450" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));

        canvas.selectionColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
        canvas.selectionBorderColor = 'red';
        canvas.selectionLineWidth = 5;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Option**

You can download `fabric.js` in any format from [**HERE**](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tree/master/dist)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using an unreleased version from version control. There is a download of the released version available and the original question implies (by discussing "the unzipped file") that they already have it.

Comment: Ah, I see. It looks like I was downloading a completely different version that was linked on their website. Thank you! What I downloaded was a massive zip full of a ton of different js files. Edit: Actually it looks like I downloaded the right file, and I was just confused as to the place to link to.

Comment: How can i use image in place of draw circle?